# connect java with php

Tags: java, php, android, json

I'm facing a lot of trouble with PHP and java android because of depreciated codes I tried earlier to connect my android app with a database without using override and JSON and I failed now I'm using the latest updates and still fail to connect PHP pdo with java android using JSON please help

---

I added to the manifest

---

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses- 
 permission>
```

---

my PHP code and I tested HTML and it worked with JSON codes

---

```
<?php
   include "conn.php";

   $Fname = $_POST['Fname'];
   $Lname = $_POST['Lname'];
   $Email = $_POST['Email'];
   $Password = $_POST['Password'];

   $sql_verify = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email = :EMAIL";
   $stmt = $PDO->prepare($sql_verify);
   $stmt->bindParam(':EMAIL', $Email);
   $stmt->execute();

   if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {

    $returnApp = array( 'SIGNUP' => 'Email_Already_Exist');

    echo json_encode($returnApp);
       }else{

    $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO users (Fname, Lname, Email, Password)VALUES 
   (:FNAME, :LNAME, :EMAIL, :PASSWORD);";
    $stmt = $PDO->prepare($sql_insert);

    $stmt->bindParam(':FNAME', $Fname);
    $stmt->bindParam(':LNAME', $Lname);
    $stmt->bindParam(':EMAIL', $Email);
    $stmt->bindParam(':PASSWORD', $Password);

    if($stmt->execute()){
        $returnApp = array( 'SIGNUP' => 'Sign_Up_Success');

echo json_encode($returnApp);

    }else{
        $returnApp = array( 'SIGNUP' => 'Sign_Up_Failed');

echo json_encode($returnApp);

    }

}
```

---

My java code

---

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

 import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
 import com.koushikdutta.async.future.FutureCallback;
 import com.koushikdutta.ion.Ion;

public class SignupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText etFname, etLname, etEmail, etPassword,etPasswrod2 ;
private Button btnSignup;


private String HOST = "http://My IP ADDRESS/android";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

    etFname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFname);
    etLname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLname);
    etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    etPasswrod2 =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword2);

    btnSignup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSignup);

    btnSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String Fname = etFname.getText().toString();
            String Lname = etLname.getText().toString();
            String Email = etEmail.getText().toString();
            String Password = etPassword.getText().toString();
            String Password2 = etPasswrod2.getText().toString();

            String URL = HOST + "/signup.php";

            if (Password2.equals(Password)) {

                if(Fname.isEmpty() || Lname.isEmpty() || Email.isEmpty() || 
        Password.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "All Fields Are 
        Required", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else {
                    Ion.with(SignupActivity.this)
                            .load(URL)
                            .setBodyParameter("Fname", Fname)
                            .setBodyParameter("Lname", Lname)
                            .setBodyParameter("Email", Email)
                            .setBodyParameter("Password", Password)
                            .asJsonObject()
                            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(Exception e, 
    JsonObject result) {

                                    try {

   //Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Name: " + 
   result.get("NAME").getAsString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        String RETURN = 
   result.get("SIGNUP").getAsString();


   if(RETURN.equals("Email_Already_Exist")) {

   Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Ops! Email_Already_Exist", 
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }else 
   if(RETURN.equals("Sign_Up_Success")) {

  Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Sign_Up_Success", 
 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }else{

Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Ops! Error Occurred", 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }

                                    } catch (Exception error) {
                                        Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, 
 "Ops! Error Occured" + error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }

                                }
                            });
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Password Do Not Match", 
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: What problem are you encountering now?

Comment: What kind of error(s) did you face?

Comment: JSON echo doesnt show up and data doesnt get inserted in the database

Comment: while other JSON errors like all fields are required and password dont match appear

Comment: so is it in the php or java ? sorry its literally my first day using jason

Comment: Can you log or print the exception by getting `e.getMessage()` or `e.printStackTrace();` and send it here

Comment: String RETURN = result.get("SIGNUP").getAsString();
the get in result.get changes to red

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I didn't understand the docs clearly, I delete my comment now.

Comment: its okay .. i just dont know what to do as a self learner with code depreciated and most of the online courses are outdated im not sure what to do except asking people here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out the solution the EMULATOR WAS OFFLINE :D:D thanks alot for everyone who tried to help .. im not sure if i should delete the question or leave it for the people who try to connect database using PHP PDO with java JSON